# How do you properly set a workingDirectory for a Node.js with vue azure pipeline?

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

This is my script, but I don't know how to properly declare my workingDirectory path.

```
# Node.js with Vue
# Build a Node.js project that uses Vue.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
```

*This is the area of my script that I don;t know if I am properly declaring.*

```
- script: |
    npm install
    npm install --save axios vue-router
    npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
  workingDirectory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/countries'
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you need to confirm the path of the package.json file in your project.

By default, the source file will be download to `(build.sourcesdirectory)`

Then you could define the **workingDirectory** in the script task.

For example: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)\foldername(the package.json file location)`

File structure：

[image]

Yaml sample:

```
- script: 'npm install'
  workingDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/pack'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

Here is the doc about [Pipeline Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: Do you know of a way to set the workingDirectory for an entire job or does it need to be at script level? I did check the ADO documents and it looks like it can't be set at a job level

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I just created for me.

```
# Node.js with Vue
# Build a Node.js project that uses Vue.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- feature/new-extension-v3

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js v18'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  workingDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/MyWebsite'
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```